# How to display more than 3 values at a time in a NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker

I'm creating a number picker as indicated in the attached image below but I want to show more than 3 values if space is available. This picker has 20 items and there is plenty of room to show more than 3 values. Can this be accomplished using NumberPicker?

[image]

Comment: I think you would have to make your own custom copy of NumberPicker in order to get that behavior unfortunately.

Comment: I wonder if it would be easier to get the NumberPicker source and modify it or try to duplicate the same thing using a list.  The big thing that I must replicate is the selector in the middle.

Comment: That is what I mean, start with their code and modify it, not create from scratch.

Comment: I have answered this question here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49790141/display-more-numbers-in-numberpicker)

Answer (score -9):

just set Programatically `numberPicker.setWheelItemCount(10);`

Comment: doesn't work, can't  find the method itself https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker

Comment: then try this https://github.com/AigeStudio/WheelPicker