# Display more numbers in NumberPicker

Tags: android, numberpicker, android-number-picker

I have two issues, first one is removing the divider in the NumberPicker and I'm extending the NumberPicker in Android to solve this issue, like this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;


public class ExtendedNumberPicker extends NumberPicker {

    public ExtendedNumberPicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);

        Class<?> numberPickerClass = null;
        try {
            numberPickerClass = Class.forName("android.widget.NumberPicker");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Field selectionDivider = null;
        try {
            selectionDivider = numberPickerClass.getDeclaredField("mSelectionDivider");
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            selectionDivider.setAccessible(true);
            selectionDivider.set(this, null);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

My other issue is that I didn't find any way to display more than 3 elements like the below UI:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Set Removing divider lines

```
<NumberPicker
   ...
   android:theme="@style/DefaultNumberPickerTheme" />
```

style.xml

```
<style name="DefaultNumberPickerTheme" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

For the other part : Checkout this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15776716/how-to-display-more-than-3-values-at-a-time-in-a-numberpicker)

Hope this helps !